# Sharing AWS AMI Images Between Accounts Not Working - Image not visible

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-ami

The initial motivation for the activity below was the need to move my Wordpress site (based on Bitnami) from one AWS account to another. In order to do that I have found the following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aITdIDIkkao
I am doing all the steps as described in the tutorial until 7:11, where shared AMI Image needs to appear in another account. Unfortunately, this is not happening - I can't see the image on my second account.

Can anyone please help?
And is this the right approach to move my wordpress site from one AWS account to another?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Found it - apparently I need to look in the same region.